# Maintain naming standard for variables with Lombok @Getter AND @Setter

Tags: java, coding-style, standards, lombok

The code base I work with uses the naming standard for every local variable to start with an 's' or and 'f' e.g. fName or sName. When I use Lombok @Getter annotation with it, it ends up naming the functions as getFName() or getSName() which doesn't look pretty.

Do you have any advice or suggestions on how you guys maintain the naming guidelines/standards while using Lombok?

Comment: Lombok is actually doing it wrong, the getter should be `getfName()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a *lombok.config* file in your project root with the following contents:

```
lombok.accessors.prefix += f
lombok.accessors.prefix += s
```

See [here](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html) for `lombok.accessors.prefix` parameter description and [here](https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration.html) for instructions on *lombok.config* file usage.

Or better, if at all possible, get rid of this naming convention altogether.